# How to subset a fasta file using data frames containing specific IDs in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have one complex fasta file containing 794 entries that I would like to subset based on various lists of IDs I have created.

The fasta file is in the format shown below:

```
>5_B1_CZ.1:572-889 ID:5_B1 Contig:1 
ATGTCCTGGATDCGTTACTTGTGTATTGCCGGTCCTC
```

Based on a previous answer, I read the fasta file in using the code below.

```
fastafile<- read.fasta(file = "test.fasta", seqtype = "AA",as.string = TRUE, set.attributes = FALSE)
```

And then used the following line to subset the fasta file based on a a data frame containing a list of IDs.

```
f<-fastafile[c(which(names(fastafile) %in% Allint$`All Intersect`))]
```

An example of the ID list is shown below.

```
All Intersect
1 5_F2_CZ.13:475-2241
2 2_B8_CZ.9:133-1899
```

This seemed to work but gave an output that had the various fasta ID as column headers with the sequences in the rows below. (As shown in Image 1)

I have had trouble trying to export this as a complete fasta file due to this format.

Is there an easier way to complete this task?

Sorry if this is convoluted, I am new to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1) To subset your fasta object you do no need `c` or `which`

```
f<-fastafile[names(fastafile) %in% Allint$`All Intersect`)]
```

2) To output the sequences you have subset you will want to use the `write.fasta` function. This will put the sequence back together and write a fasta file.

```
write.fasta(f, names(f), file.out="My_newfastaFile.fa")
```